# Pikachoose - Initiate vertical-centering script on image change

Tags: jquery, vertical-alignment, image-gallery

I have a jQuery script vertically an horizontally centering an image within a div. This works great for the first image loaded into the Pikachoose slider, but I need the script to reinitialize when Pikachoose changes slides--making the next image vertically and horizontally center.

Here's the vertical/center script working on the image:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $img = $('img.galleryfull');
    var h = $img.height();
    $img.css('margin-top', +h / -2 + "px");
    var w = $img.width();
    $img.css('margin-left', +w / -2 + "px");
});
```

How do I reinitialize this when PikaChoose loads the next image in the gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.pikachoose.com/versions/), there is the `animationComplete` callback that you could use. Something like this should work...

Wrap your code in a function:

```
function centreImage() {
    var $img = $('img.galleryfull');
    var h = $img.height();
    $img.css('margin-top', +h / -2 + "px");
    var w = $img.width();
    $img.css('margin-left', +w / -2 + "px");
}
```

Call your function when the page loads:

```
$(window).load( centreImage());
```

Call your function when the image changes:

```
$("#id").PikaChoose({animationFinished: centreImage});
```

Comment: Genius! I'm just starting out with jQuery, so the syntax sometimes gets confusing. Thank you again!!!